# Postgresql "Missing From-Clause Error"

Tags: postgresql

I have two versions of PostgreSQL (8.0.4 / 8.1.4) and have noticed that in 8.1.4 I get a "Missing From-Clause Error" for the following statement:

```
DELETE FROM MDFUSERGROUPREL_DELETED 
WHERE userid = MDFUSERGROUPREL.userid 
AND usergroupid = MDFUSERGROUPREL.usergroupid 
AND userid=?
```

As you cannot do a DELETE with SELECT statement in 8.0.4 I am using a direct table reference instead, but this seems to be causing a problem in 8.1.4

Is anyone able to confirm this behaviour and if possible provide a work around?

I know the versions i am using are old and not supported this is a environmental constraint so no I can't just upgrade it.

Comment: What do you intend to do? Delete records that `EXIST` in another table ? Also what are the asterixes at \*MDFUSERGROUPREL\* ?

Comment: Yep, please show the **exact text** of the original query and the **full, exact text** of the error message.

Comment: i removed the asterixes which were a result of using the italics format in the stackoverflow text editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're relying on a behaviour of old versions of PostgreSQL which used to implicitly add `FROM` clauses when tables were referenced that weren't listed in `FROM`. You'll be able to see this in an `EXPLAIN` of your query.

This misfeature was removed from PostgreSQL. It caused accidental cross-products on typos and was generally a very bad idea. You can re-enable it as a temporary workaround by setting the [`add_missing_from`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-compatible.html) configuration parameter to true either with a `SET` statement before the problem query or in `postgresql.conf`. This backwards compatibility workaround was removed in 9.0, so you cannot use it to get your app working with 9.0 or above. I've intentionally linked to the 8.4 version of the documentation because the parameter was removed from later versions.

See [this mailing list discussion](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200304291436.43249.josh@agliodbs.com).

The cause of the problem in this query is that you're doing an implicit join on `MDFUSERGROUPREL`. You should be naming this table explicitly in your `USING` clause in the `DELETE` statement.

Here's a demo showing the problem and workaround: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/6c4b3/4 ... and here's a demo showing how to do it correctly two different ways: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/6c4b3/7 . The 1st is a simple fix that just adds the missing from clause to the query and fixes the resulting column name conflicts:

```
DELETE FROM MDFUSERGROUPREL_DELETED
USING MDFUSERGROUPREL
WHERE MDFUSERGROUPREL_DELETED.userid = MDFUSERGROUPREL.userid 
AND MDFUSERGROUPREL_DELETED.usergroupid = MDFUSERGROUPREL.usergroupid 
AND MDFUSERGROUPREL_DELETED.userid=1;
```

You will find that the latter two examples result in the same query plan at least on modern versions of PostgreSQL, so it doesn't make a difference whether you use `EXISTS` or a join.

I've followed your query's original style in not using table aliases, but I strongly suggest that you do use aliases for readability. See @wildplasser's example.

Comment: Thanks Craig, i have added the parameter and it is working now.

Comment: @Graham You understand that this is a *temporary hack* right, a *transitional* option until you can fix your code? That it *does not work with newer versions*? You need to fix your query. If you must set `add_missing_from`, do it with a `SET` statement in the session rather than globally in `postgresql.conf` if possible, so you don't introduce more errors.

Comment: @Graham Also, seriously, get on to management to wake up - you're not just running an unsupported old version, you're running a totally ancient patch release with multiple known severe bugs. At minimum update to 8.0.26 (two years + worth of fixes) or the latest 8.1, then begin planning an *urgent* upgrade to a modern stack before you get permanently stuck supporting an every growing pile of legacy crud nobody cares about or remembers anymore.

Comment: I do understand everything you have said and appreciated it. I am changing the sql and will remove the parameter once its done.

Comment: @Graham Glad to help. http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ might help when convincing whatever management types you're contending with that they have a real problem and need to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Not understanding your exact intentions, it still appears to me that `exists` might do the trick:

```
DELETE FROM MDFUSERGROUPREL_DELETED del
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM MDFUSERGROUPRE ex
    WHERE ex.userid = del.userid 
    AND ex.usergroupid = del.usergroupid
    ) 
AND del.userid=?
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you got the gist of my question.

Comment: @Graham Quick tip for the future: Such questions are way easier to answer with info about what the query is supposed to do, exact text of errors, table definitions shown, etc.